# How can I create rounded diagonal lines in Java using the ACM library?

Tags: java, graphics, acm-java-libraries

I am trying to draw rounded diagonal lines in Java using the ACM library.

A very complicated method would involve drawing a diagonal line, scaling it up to increase its width, drawing an arc on the top of that line with respect to the angles it is rounded.

Comment: What do you mean by "rounded diagonal lines"? Can you post a picture?

Comment: the antenna are what i want to create http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Android_robot.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the picture you linked to, it looks like you want lines with round end-caps, sometimes called line-joins. I don't know the ACM library too well, but looking at the docs for it, it seems like you could achieve that look by using a [`GPen`](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GPen.html) with an image that is just a filled-in circle. You could call the `setLocation(x,y)` and then `drawLine(dx, dy)` methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ACM but looking at the javadoc you might want to consider using shapes rather then lines.  So for example, you can draw a rectangle of width using [GPolygon](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GPolygon.html) then draw circles on the ends using [GOval](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GOval.html)

So something like: draw a polygon around the points [100,0],[0,100],[10,110],[110,10], then draw two circles of size 10 at 0,110 and 110,0.  If those shapes are all filled with the same color, they should look like one solid.